# Не работает цикл с строками

Tags: c++, c

Делаю курсовую по касе автовоказала, и все функции работают кроме DateEntry. Когда вызываю функцию через switch запускается цикл для заполнения массива, но массив прерывается в середине, и не знаю как решить эту проблему.

Ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Сам код:**

**Functions.cpp**

```
void DataEntry(Date* (&d), int& n){
cout << "Введiть скiльки маршутiв ви хочете добавити: ";
cin >> n;

d = new Date[n];
int choose_m;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cout << "Введiть iнформацiю про маршут:" << endl;
    cout << "Номер маршуту: ";
    cin >> d[i]._trans.num_t;
    cout << "Пункт Призначення: ";
    cin >> d[i]._trans.destination;
    cout << "Дистанцiя: ";
    cin >> d[i]._trans.distance;
    cout << "Мiсто виЇзду: ";
    cin >> d[i]._trans.city;
    cout << "Введiть iнформацiю про бiлет: " << endl;
    cout << "Номер бiлету: ";
    cin >> d[i]._tick.ID_tick;
    cout << "Мiсце продажi: ";
    cin >> d[i]._tick.place;
    cout << "Цiна: ";
    cin >> d[i]._tick.price;

    cout << "Введiть iмя Диспетчера: ";
    cin >> d[i]._dis.D_name;

    cout << "Водiй: " << endl;
    cout << "Введiть iмя водiя: ";
    cin >> d[i]._driv.d_name;
    cout << "Номер телефону: ";
    cin >> d[i]._driv.num_phone;

    cout << "Автобус: " << endl;
    cout << "Номернi знаки автобуса: ";
    cin >> d[i]._b.num_bus;
    cout << "Модель: ";
    cout << "[0] - BMW" << endl;
    cout << "[1] - Mercedes" << endl;
    cout << "[2] - Hyundai" << endl;
    cin >> choose_m;
    switch (choose_m)
    {
    case 0: d[i]._b.model = "BMW"; break;
    case 1: d[i]._b.model = "Mercedes"; break;
    case 2: d[i]._b.model = "Hyundai"; break;
    }
    cout << "Колiр автобуса: ";
    cin >> d[i]._b.color;

    cout << "_______________________________________" << endl;
}
}
```

**Functions.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Transportation // Маршут
{
    int num_t;
    string destination;
    int distance;
    int city;
};
struct Tickets // Бiлет
{
    int ID_tick;
    string place;
    double price;
};

struct Dispatcher // Диспетчер
{
    string D_name;
};

struct Driver // Водiй
{
    string d_name;
    int num_phone;
};
struct Bus {
    int num_bus;
    string model;
    string color;

};

struct Date {
    Transportation _trans;
    Tickets _tick;
    Dispatcher _dis;
    Driver _driv;
    Bus _b;
};

void DataEntry(Date* (&d), int& n);
```

**Source.cpp**

```
#include "Functions.h"

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int amount = 0;
    Date* d = new Date[amount];
    DataEntry(d, amount);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправьте поле структуры.

```
struct Transportation // Маршут
{
    int num_t;
    string destination;
    int distance;

    //int city; - Ошибка!
    string сity;
};
```

Comment: После заполения строки -    cin >> d[i]._trans.city;    Консоль ничего не показывает и никаких действий нету

Comment: @Zar1s, а почему у вас поле city имеет тип int?

Comment: @Zar1s вы пытались ввести символы в переменную типа int. Исправьте int на string в структуре Transportation.

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Comment: @Zar1s, не за что, будьте повнимательнее. Успехов в обучении!

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо убрать последний break.:

```
case 2: d[i]._b.model = "Hyundai"; break; 
-> 
case 2: d[i]._b.model = "Hyundai";
```

Comment: Я убрал, но цикл осстанавливается на структре _tick

Comment: Я добавил ещё  файл заголовок

Comment: Весь ввод информации а точнее операторы cin >> пропускает и сразу же выводит пустые значение массива и cout >>

Comment: @Zar1s, Возможно в потоке cin остается \n. попробуйте очистить поток cin. Вот так: while (cin.get() != '\n');

Comment: А куда это добавить?

Comment: В функцию или в int main? Или массив должен быть в while?

Comment: Цикл в while закинул, теперь только пустая консоль

Comment: Добавил в место где начиналась ошибка - вечный цикл.